# How to coordinate ports between docker containers

Tags: docker

I have installed docker to host several containers on a server, using the host network - so ports are shared amongst all containers. If one container uses port 8000, no other ones can. Is there a tool - perhaps not so complex as k8s, though I've no idea whether that can do it - to assist me with selecting ports for each container? As the number of services on the host network grows, managing the list of available ports becomes unwieldy.

I remain confused as to why when I run `docker ps`, certain containers list no ports at all. It would be easier if the full list of ports were easily available, but I have two containers with a sizable list of exposed ports which show no ports at all. I suppose this is a separate question and a less important one.

Comment: Docker Swarm is less popular than k8, but easier to understand https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/. In this model each container becomes its own service accessible at a different host name, so all services could in theory expose the same port and not conflct

Comment: You're disabling Docker's networking stack by using host networking, so you've lost the ability to remap ports, and anything a service happens to listen on won't be reported in Docker's metadata.

Comment: @DavidMaze that explains a lot, thank you. I suppose this is evidence I should be looking at macvlan to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Containers in a Pod are accessible via “localhost”; they use the same network namespace. Also, for containers, the observable host name is a Pod’s name. Because containers share the same IP address and port space, you should use different ports in containers for incoming connections. In other words, applications in a Pod must coordinate their usage of ports.

In the following example, we will create a multi-container Pod where nginx in one container works as a reverse proxy for a simple web application running in the second container.

Step 1. Create a ConfigMap with the nginx configuration file. Incoming HTTP requests to port 80 will be forwarded to port 5000 on localhost
Step 2. Create a multi-container Pod with the simple web app and nginx in separate containers. Note that for the Pod, we define only nginx port 80. Port 5000 will not be accessible outside of the Pod.
Step 3. Expose the Pod using the NodePort service:
$ kubectl expose pod mc3 --type=NodePort --port=80
service "mc3" exposed
Now you can use your browser (or curl) to navigate to your node’s port  to access the web application.

it’s quite common for several containers in a Pod to listen on different ports — all of which need to be exposed. To make this happen, you can either create a single service with multiple exposed ports, or you can create a single service for every poirt you’re trying to expose.